# docker nginx deployment entrypoint

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a dockerized nginx that works great if I run a shell, but (naturally enough) if I give "nginx start" itself as the entrypoint, it just daemonizes and exits immediately for lack of a process to wait for.

My inclination is just to do something like this:

```
pid=$(cat /run/nginx.pid)
while ps ax | awk '{print $1}' | grep -q $pid; do
    sleep 60
done
```

Though this seems like quite a hack. But when I google for examples, I see people running bash.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well I opened up the [Dockerfile from the official nginx container](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/04d0c5754673d6880b91e94c3cebaa767d9a1af7/Dockerfile) for you and saw they use:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Yup, I just found that, too (doh!). Thanks.